# how to access np array element according to its last element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Actually, I am doing a sequence operation about `numpy array`, therefore, I want to know how to access `a[i]` quickly?

(Because I access`a[i-1]` in the last loop, therefore, in `c++`, we may simply access `a[i]` by adding 1 to the address of `a[i-1]`,but I don't know whether it is possible in numpy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible/`a[i]` is the fastest way.

Python is a programming language that is easier to learn (and use) than `c++`, this of course comes at a cost, one of these costs is, that it's slower.

The references you're talking about can be "dangerous", hence python makes them not (easily) available to people, to protect them from things the do not understand.

While references are faster, you can't use them in python (as it is anyway slower, the difference in using references or not doesn't matter that much)

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to think of a Python [NumPy: ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) as a C++ array.  They're much different.  Python also offers its own native [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) objects and includes an [array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module in its standard libraries.

A Python list behaves mostly like a generic array (as found in many programming languages).  It's an ordered sequence; elements can be accessed by integer index from 0 up through (but not including) the length of the list (*len(mylist)*); ranges of elements can be access using "slice" notation (*mylist[start_offset:end_offset]*) returning another list object; negative indexes are treated as offsets from the end of the list (*mylist[-1]* is the last item of the list) and so on.

Additionally they support a number of methods such as *.count()*, *.find()* and *.replace()*.

Unlike the arrays in most programming languages, Python lists are heterogenous.  The elements can be any mixture of any object types in Python, including references to nested lists, dictionaries, code, classes, generator objects and other callable first class objects and, of course, instances of custom objects.

The Python array module allows one to instantiate homogenous list-like objects.  That is you instantiate them using any of a dozen primitive data types (character or Unicode, signed or unsigned short or long integers, floating point or double precision floating point).  Indexing and slicing are identical to Python native lists.

The primary advantage of Python *array.array()* instances is that they can store large numbers of their elements far more compactly than the more generalized list objects.  Various operations on these arrays are likely to be somewhat faster than similar operations performed by iterating over or otherwise referencing elements in a native Python list because there's greater locality of reference in the more compact array layout (in memory) and because the type constraint obviates some dispatch overhead that's incurred when handling generalized objects.

[NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), on the other hand, is far more sophisticated than the Python *array* module.

For one thing the *ndarray* can be multi-dimensional and can be dynamically reshaped.  It's common to start with a linear *ndarray* and to reshape it into a matrix or other higher dimensional structure.  Also the *ndarray* supports a much richer set of data types than the Python *array* module.  NumPy also implements some rather advanced [fancy indexing](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing)features.

But the real performance advantages of NumPy relate to how it "vectorizes" most operations, broadcasts them across the data structures (possibly using any [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) features supported by your CPU or even your GPU in the process.  At the very list many common matrix operations, when properly written in Python for NumPy, are execute as native machine code speed. This performance edge does well beyond the minor effects of locality of references and obviating dispatch tables that one gains using the simple *array* module.